# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}=1$ geometrically

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}=1,$$ but I am looking for a geometrical prove. I found this picture:

[image]

Can somebody explain in what way this explains my statement?

Comment: Each upward pointing rectangle has area $\frac{1}{2}^{2k+1}$, whereas each square in the top right corner has area $\frac{1}{2}^{2k}$. Add up the areas to get a square of area $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write out the series of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}$$ you'll get $\frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 18 +  \ldots$ which respectively represents the area of the rectangle because the total area of the square is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the first rectangle is half of square , the second is half of half ,the 3rd is half of half of half ,...

Comment: Could at least use write the numbers out decently/legibly.